# Error HH100: Network rinkeby doesn't exist

Tags: solidity

This is the top half of my hardhat.config

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});
```

I keeping getting the same "Error HH100: Network rinkeby doesn't exist" when I run `npx hardhat run scripts/deployPizzaHeadNFT --network rinkeby`

Bottom half of hardhat.config

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_RINKEBY_RPC_URL
      accounts: [process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ETHERSCAN_KEY,
  },
};
```

Comment: is hardhat config file in correct location. it should be at same level as package.json

Comment: Yeah it is at the same level

Comment: Did you find a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
[`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
```

Check `0x${}` to be sure it's in your `PRIVATE_KEY`.